# NSURLCache - When does it expire?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Alamofire Framework for HTTP requests in my app. Even though by standard URLCaching is not ON, Alamofire sets it as default.

> Caching
>
> Caching is handled on the system framework level by NSURLCache.
> https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#caching

I understand that caching is important for performance (network, CPU etc.) but if caching is not expiring after some minutes, caching prevents the app from checking whether if the remote content has changed or not.

I also have read a lot of articles explaining how efficient method caching is and how recommended for use.

Then my question is, when will the cached data expire? Will it ever expire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cache will expire based on the 'Cache-Control' HTTP-Header contained within the response to the request.

NSURLSession uses NSURLCache for this, and since Alamofire uses NSURLSession under the hood, the Cache-Control header is what determines the expiry time.

Comment: Folowing your answer I googled 'Cache-Control' and I searched inside the response output again.  Is "Keep-Alive" (which is the only field in the response header that might be related with caching,?)  determining caching timeout in my case?

Comment: Look at Alamofire's CacheTests.swift file (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Tests/CacheTests.swift). It has a bunch of test cases which should be able to explain what exactly the caching does. As far as the Keep-Alive is concerned, it only specifies the timeout for the underlying TCP connection used to make the HTTP requests.